# Capturing div as image and exporting to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, screen-capture

I want to capture a `div` as an image and export the results to an .xls file and make this file available for download. Are there any libraries that support this for jQuery/JavaScript? This is a JSP page and I'm using Java.

Edit: my original goal was to create a .xls file using Java and generate line-graphs using Java and make this available for download. I found out that this can be quite a difficult task and haven't found any great libraries for this. The line-graphs that would be generated for the .xls file would be near identical to the line-graphs that I've generated using jqPlot, so I thought there could be a way where I could export the line-graphs that I've generated in jqPlot, which are contained in a div to a .xls file.

There are no architecture requirements for this. I'm using AJAX calls to receive data, which is handled by Java and SQL. The front-end is done in jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript cannot access the client file system. ActiveX can, but not JavaScript.

Comment: @abc123 What about the server file system, and make that file available via download?

Comment: Here's an example using html2canvas and PHP to convert elements into an image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721286/screenshot-of-a-div-with-html2canvas-sent-to-php-saved-corrupted-image - this might solve part of your problem. You should add the code you've already tried to your question so it's easier to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401638/export-as-xls-file-not-work-when-large-data#comment28757562_19401638

Comment: @sportsfan72 in this case, I think you should update your question

Comment: @sportsfan72 Update your question, possibly delete this one and make a new one with more information...  In any case as written this question isn't solvable...without using some server side language.  JavaScript would have to call a web service to make this file, so let me know...

Comment: @Joe, I haven't added any code for this, I was previously trying to generate graphs for excel using Java, but I haven't found any good libraries for this.

Comment: @abc123, what else should I add to the question? thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to capture the div as an image, rather than, say, comma-separated values? What's in this div, and why do you want it in Excel?

Comment: @user1618143, I want to capture it as an image because the image displays as a line-graph that shows trends, and csv wouldn't visually show the trends. In the div is a line-graph. I could instead use .csv rather than .xls, but I'm not sure if I would be able to export an image to a csv file.

Comment: You're right, CSVs can't contain images. How is the line graph built? It may be simpler to export the original data and rebuild the graph in Excel. Also, I have no idea what libraries are out there, but I think it might be easier to build an OpenOffice spreadsheet than an Excel one.

Comment: @sportsfan72 You should include your back-end language, also should include what you've tried and any architecture requirements.

Comment: @abc123, I've updated the question, not sure what else to add to it.